# Invalid hook call using Material-UI in a React-TS project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have following functional component using Material-UI:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Table, TableBody, TableCell, TableContainer, TableHead, TableRow, Paper } from '@material-ui/core';

interface RowData {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const TableExample: React.FC = () => {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState<RowData[]>([
    { id: 1, name: 'John', age: 25 },
    { id: 2, name: 'Jane', age: 30 },
    { id: 3, name: 'Bob', age: 40 },
  ]);

  const headers = ['ID', 'Name', 'Age'];

  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            {headers.map((header) => (
              <TableCell key={header}>{header}</TableCell>
            ))}
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map((row) => (
            <TableRow key={row.id}>
              <TableCell>{row.id}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{row.name}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{row.age}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
};

export default TableExample;
```

However I get following error

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at resolveDispatcher (bundle.js:10297:17)
    at Object.useContext (bundle.js:10303:24)
    at useTheme (bundle.js:3470:50)
    at useStyles (bundle.js:3314:70)
    at WithStyles (bundle.js:3551:21)
    at renderWithHooks (bundle.js:32016:22)
    at updateForwardRef (bundle.js:34587:24)
    at beginWork (bundle.js:36634:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (bundle.js:21608:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (bundle.js:21652:20)

The above error occurred in the <WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableContainer))> component:

    at WithStyles (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:3545:31)
    at TableExample (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:114:74)
    at div
    at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

I already checked if I have multiple React-modules installed using `npm ls react` which resulted into:

```
├─┬ @emotion/react@11.10.6
│ ├─┬ @emotion/use-insertion-effect-with-fallbacks@1.0.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ └── react@18.2.0
├─┬ @emotion/style@0.8.0
│ ├─┬ @emotion/core@0.13.1
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ @emotion/styled@11.10.6
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ @mui/material@5.11.13
│ ├─┬ @mui/base@5.0.0-alpha.121
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ @mui/system@5.11.13
│ │ ├─┬ @mui/private-theming@5.11.13
│ │ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ │ ├─┬ @mui/styled-engine@5.11.11
│ │ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ @mui/utils@5.11.13
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ react-dom@18.2.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ react-transition-group@4.4.5
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ @testing-library/react@13.4.0
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
└─┬ react-scripts@5.0.1
  └── react@18.2.0 deduped
```

(I assume deduped means in this case that this is not an issue)

And here is my `package.json`-file:

```js
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/style": "^0.8.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.8",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.13",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.18",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

If I replace the MUI-parts with a regular table the issue goes away. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Post the full error message including stack trace. It's possibly a bug in MUI (unlikely but possible), but there's no way to tell without that information.

Comment: Apologies, I added the complete error-message to the post

Comment: Sir as a test can you try pasting the exact table that MUI has here for 'Basic Table' https://mui.com/material-ui/react-table/   .  You also might benefit from deleting node_modules first and doing install

Answer (score 0):

[@terpinmd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3542351/terpinmd) pointed me in the right direction and I was able to solve the problem thanks to his help. The solution goes as follows:

```
import Table from '@mui/material/Table';
import TableBody from '@mui/material/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@mui/material/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@mui/material/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@mui/material/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@mui/material/TableRow';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Ausschreibung } from '../interfaces/interfaces';

export default function BasicTable() {

    const [data, setData] = useState<Ausschreibung[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://example.com/api/data')
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => setData(data))
          .catch((error) => console.error(error));
      }, []);

  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Titel</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Datum</TableCell>
            <TableCell>höchstes Ranking</TableCell>
            <TableCell>passende Mitarbeiter</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {data.map((item) => (
            <TableRow key={item.id}>
              <TableCell>{item.title}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{item.import_date.toLocaleDateString("de-DE")}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{Math.random()*10}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{Math.random()*10}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
      </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

Now I have to admit that I do not know why this solved the issue, if anyone can explain why this works that'd be great